# How to pass a case class into a function parameter and get a schema accordingly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

[the function which will return me the schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxO24.png)I made a function called getschema(MyCaseClass) which will return me the schema by encoding using Encoders.product[MyCaseClass].schema but Encoders.product is not taking that case class as a parameter.

```
case class Moviedata(id:Int, name:String, year:Int, rating:Double,duration:Int)

//calling the function defined in another class
val movieSchema = getSchema(Moviedata)


//this is not working
def getSchema[T](t:Class[T])={
    Encoders.product[t].schema
}

//this works when defined in the same class but how to generalize into a function
//val movieSchema = Encoders.product[Moviedata].schema
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: not found: type t @Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example, don't forget about the import

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

case class Moviedata(id:Int, name:String, year:Int, rating:Double,duration:Int)

val movieSchema = getSchema(Moviedata)

def getSchema[T <: Product : TypeTag]={
  Encoders.product[T].schema
}
```

Some explanations.
`Encoders.product` takes `type parameter` not a class and doesn't have arguments.

```
def getSchema[T]={
    Encoders.product[T].schema
}
```

Unfortunately, it is still not enough for the compiler, it needs to know the runtime type of your instance. Scala's way to provide it is via `TypeTag` trait that is added as an implicit parameter.

```
def getSchema[T](implicit t : TypeTag[T])={
  Encoders.product[T].schema
}
```

Or in a more concise way:

```
def getSchema[T : TypeTag]={
    Encoders.product[T].schema
}
```

But there is another restriction, your class must also be a `Product`

```
def getSchema[T <: Product : TypeTag]={
  Encoders.product[T].schema
}
```

Comment: could you please explain the last line why my class must also be a Product @Gelerion

Comment: Product is a trait in Scala which provides access to all the elements of a base class.
All case classes are extending Product trait so that Spark can convert them to and from the internal row format using catalyst expressions.

Comment: For some reason, I get a `No TypeTag available for MyCaseClass` - I'm using `import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders` and `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._` Question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77248745/how-to-get-the-spark-case-class-schema)