# How to get the spark case class schema and UDFs with missing TypeTag?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import org.apache.spark
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

case class StationX(  stnId: Int,
                    wbanId: Int,
                    lat: Double,
                    lon: Double)
object Inst {
  def getSchema[T <: Product : TypeTag] = Encoders.product[T].schema
  val ss = getSchema[StationX]
}
```

The above produces an error:
`No TypeTag available for observatory.StationX` at `val ss = getSchema[StationX]`

How can this code be corrected?

This works in the spark shell REPL but not in my project.

EDITS Deleted and replaced with a complete way to reproduce.

A way to reproduce:

[Download project](https://moocs.scala-lang.org/%7Edockermoocs/handouts/scala-3/observatory.zip)

Test build of main, then add an object:

```
package observatory
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

case class CC(i: Int)
object SparkInstance {
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Spark SQL UDF scalar example")
    .getOrCreate()

 // ** These don't work (or maybe just the def works) **

  def getSchema[T <: Product : TypeTag] = Encoders.product[T].schema

  // No TypeTag available for Double
  val random = udf(() => Math.random())

  // No TypeTag available for Int
  val plusOne = udf((x: Int) => x + 1)

  // No TypeTag available for observatory.CC
  val ss = getSchema[CC]
}
```

and build.

Uses : Scala 3.3.0, Spark 3.2 is excluded, to enable remove the excludes in build.sbt

Comment: Is this the exact code? Where is the case class defined? Could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143756/scala-spark-app-with-no-typetag-available-error-in-def-main-style-app

Comment: StationX have to be declared as top-level class (not inner)

Comment: Work in databricks cell though.

Comment: @GaëlJ ... pasha701 - The case class was declared top level. This is seen in the coursera scala capstone project by others too. One guy writes he was able to use ['summon'] (https://github.com/vincenzobaz/spark-scala3), but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Ah, indeed if you are using Scala 3 you need this additional library. Please update your post with the code you wrote when using this library then.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72987147/no-typetag-available-for-a-case-class-using-scala-3-with-spark-3

Comment: @GaëlJ  - I updated the issue which now shows that the inability to get the type tag is also for basic types like Int, Double ... as well as that for case classes ... so I'm doubting that this is a duplicate of that issue. ???

Comment: Again I don't see any usage of what https://github.com/vincenzobaz/spark-scala3 is saying you should use for Scala 3. You're not importing the stuff to make it work with Scala 3.

Comment: @GaëlJ - Yeah ... I cannot figure out what I am missing ... Unfortunately ... a lot of answers in Stack Overflow are helpful with code but fail to provide helpful imports.

Comment: `import scala3encoders.given`, `import scala3udf.{Udf => udf}` is documented on the GitHub README.

Comment: @GaëlJ Of course I tried these imports ... `import scala3udf.{Udf => udf}` is not found ... this is why I gave the project in the description. I don't see anyway of doing this given the project constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these in the build.sbt:

```scala
  ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.2").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13),
  ("io.github.vincenzobaz" %% "spark-scala3-encoders" % "0.2.3"),
  ("io.github.vincenzobaz" %% "spark-scala3-udf" % "0.2.3"),
```

and code wise:

```scala
package observatory
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

import scala3encoders.given

import scala3udf.{Udf => udf}

case class CC(i: Int)
object SparkInstance {
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Spark SQL UDF scalar example")
    .getOrCreate()

  def getSchema[T : Encoder] = implicitly[Encoder[T]].schema

  val random = udf(() => Math.random())

  val plusOne = udf((x: Int) => x + 1)

  val ss = getSchema[CC]
}
```

You were mixing mechanisms, the scala3 docs state you need to use it's udf to work with the types correctly.  Similarly the getSchema function tried to create Encoders using the spark mechanism, which fails as it uses scala 2 reflection.  Using an Encoder context instead lets the spark-scala3 Encoder derivation work.

Comment: I'm sure this is the right way, but I think you're confirming that the Coursera project gives bunk advice. The primary goal was to determine if this was true and it seems to be.

Comment: both your question text and title all ask how can it be corrected, nothing about Coursera 
 until you look at the comments - that's exactly what this seemingly correct answer does.    You should accept it if it's correct or point out why it's not so others can learn from it.

Comment: Yeah - Also, while your answer is correct, per my question, I was waiting to hear from the library author and to see if there were other solutions. The author confirms my suspicions. See: https://github.com/vincenzobaz/spark-scala3/issues/48. Ka-ching for you!